# CSS Centering with nested Divs

Tags: html, css

Can anyone take a look at this and let me know what I'm doing wrong (probably something stupid)?

**I would like the Text "test" to be centered.**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/uteaH/3/

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    max-width: 1139px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;     }

#screenPresentation {
    border-top: 4px solid #d95936;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background: #fff;
}

#screenPresentation h2 {
    margin-top: -45px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    font-weight: 500;
    float:left;
}
 .loginContainer-wrapper {
    width: 99%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap" id="screenPresentation">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="loginContainer-wrapper">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What part should be centered?   The text?

Comment: You should tell us what you are trying to achieve... The only person who knows how it should look like is you.

Comment: Do we have to guess.??

Comment: Sorry about that.  Yes the test text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to be a mindreader here since you won't tell us exactly what needs to be centered

[***DEMO***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZP8fQ/)

For `#screenPresentation h2`

Remove
   `float:left;`

Replace with
   `position: absolute;`
   `width: 95%;`
   `text-align: center;`

---

```
Sorry - I updated my question. I need the text "test" centered inside the inner div.
```

Oh in that case

Remove `width:95%;text-align:center` from `#screenPresentation h2`
Add `text-align:center` to `.loginContainer-wrapper`

[***DEMO***](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZP8fQ/1/)

Comment: Sorry - I updated my question.  I need the text "test" centered inside the inner div.

Answer (score 3):

`text-align:center;` by any chance?

Comment: This alone actually won't work. The margin on the floated heading gets in the way. Why the OP laid the content out this way is confusing.

Comment: It centers the 'test' text which is what the OP asked for so this alone actually does work ;)

Comment: No, actually it doesn't: http://fiddle.jshell.net/uteaH/11/. You can see that the text is more centered than it was, but it's being pushed to the right by the heading.

Comment: @webdad3 - that depends on what you're trying to achieve. I can't tell why you're floating the heading and using a negative margin, or why you put a border on the wrapper div when it seems like it should be on the heading.

Comment: @j08691 you're wrong is not the heading that push right the text ... see my answer is just default margin

Comment: Remove the `float:left` from `#screenPresentation h2` to remove that space, then add `margin-bottom:0;` to the `#screenPresentation h2`

Comment: @Danko - no, you're wrong. Take any web inspector and look at the heading element and you'll see the heading's margin that's pushing the text. You're just removing the padding and margin on every element which includes the heading.

Answer (score 1):

To center the text you need two steps:

- First reset `margin` and `padding` for your tags:

  ```
  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }
  ```
- Second add `text-align`:

  ```
  .wrap {
    text-align:center;
  }
  ```

The demo **http://fiddle.jshell.net/uteaH/9/**

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
<center>
test
</center>
```

that will do it.

Comment: The `<center>` tag was deprecated about 15 years ago and removed from HTML5.

Comment: a) because it works means nothing and b) yes, I'm well aware that it works in some browsers.

Comment: a) being deprecated doest mean my answer is bad b) it work in all browser.

Comment: To have in mind, the Google home page use this tag ;)